# Prime numbers with While loops

Tags: java, while-loop, primes

I am trying to write a program which checks if it's prime or not and return a string yes if true and no if false. I am  trying to do it inside my main method using only while loops but I am having problems executing it. I have done it inside void method and I called the method in my main method but that is not what I want.

I want it to be inside my main method and return a String yes if it's prime and a String no if it's not prime. Any ideas please? Take a look at my code in the method below. Any ideas on how to convert it inside my main method to returns yes or no as strings?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = in .nextInt();

    isPrime(number);
  }

  public static void isPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
      return;
    } else {
      int i = 3;
      while (i <= Math.sqrt(n)) {
        if ((n % i) == 0) {
          System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
          return;
        }
        i = i + 2;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("It is a prime number");
    return;

  }

}
```

Comment: How about copying the body of `isPrime()` into `main()` where `isPrime(number);` is now? (Of course change `n` to `number` (or vice versa).)

Comment: You cannot return String from void methods.

Comment: Your isPrime method is incorrect.  Any integer less than or equal to 1 is not prime.  2 & 3 are prime.  4 is not prime.  Any integer 5 or larger can be tested for prime as you're doing in your while loop.

Comment: As Math.sqrt(n) is expensive you will want to calculate it only once, not on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Erhm, just copy and paste into your `main` method body and use `boolean` to determine what result to print out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    boolean prime = false;

    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        prime = false;
    } else {
        int i=3;
        while (i<=Math.sqrt(number)) {
            if ((number % i) == 0) {
                prime = true;
            }
            i+=2;
        }
    }

    if (prime) {
        System.out.println("It is a prime number");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your `isPrime` method return a `boolean` instead of `void`.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    int i = 3;
    while (i <= Math.sqrt(n)) {
      if ((n % i) == 0) {
        return false;
      }
      i = i + 2;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then in `main` check for

```
if(isPrime(2)) {
    System.out.println("Is a prime number!");
} else {
    System.out.println("It is not a prime number!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure what it is you want. It sounds like you want to create a function which returns yes or returns no? If this is the case, you could create the following algorithm:

```java
public static String isPrime(int num){
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num % i == 0)
            return "No";
    }
    return "Yes";
}
```

See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/) for details on how to optimize this algorithm.

Then you can just call the method in the main:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println(isPrime(number)); 
}
```

If you just want it all in your main, do like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    boolean b = true;

    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num % i == 0){
            System.out.println("No");
            b = false;
        }
    }
    if(b){
        System.out.println(isPrime(number));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Auto Generated Java Class.
 */
public class ConvertingForToWhile {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    final int MAX = 66;
    boolean isPrime = true;
    int j = 2;

    while ( j <= MAX/2 && isPrime)
    {
      if( MAX % j ==0)
      {
        isPrime = false;
      }
      j++;  
    }
    System.out.println( MAX  + " is Prime? " + isPrime );

  }



}
```

Comment: This will check the number in the max, if you want to get the number from the user just import the scan and initialize some variable like int number;

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prime
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
int num;
int count = 0;
int divide = 2;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a number user:");
num = kb.nextInt();

for(int x = 0;x<num;x++)
{
if((num%div)==0)
{
count+=1;
div = div + 1;
}
}
if(count==0)
{
System.out.println(num +" "+ "is a prime number");
}
else
{
System.out.println(num+" " +"is not a prime number");
}

}
}
```

Comment: I as an IT student in Mangosuthu University Of Technology discovered

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    
    public static boolean prime(int number){
        boolean isPrime=true;

        Integer temp=number-1;
        while (temp>1){

            if(number%temp==0){
                isPrime=false;
                break;
            }
            temp--;
        }
        return isPrime;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        System.out.println(prime(47));
    }
}
```